# How to display the rows where the revenue is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, where-clause

I have 3 tables Country(id and name),motorcycle_model(id,name,price) and sales(model_id,country_id,quantity and sales_date).
The question is to calculate the revenue in the year 2018.

The table values are as follows:-

motor_cycle table:

id  name    price

1  MOTO400 50000

2  YZM1000 70000

country table:-
id  name
1   Dominica
2   Algeria
3   Sao Tome and Principe

sales table:-
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZZ9.png)
I have combined the 3 tables using my script:-

```
select c.name,m.name,s.quantity*m.price as revenue from 
sales s,country c, motorcycle_model m
where s.model_id=m.id and s.country_id=c.id and year(s.sales_date)='2018'
group by c.name,m.name
order by m.name ;
```

and I got the output as :-
[myoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiVwr.png)

But the expected output is as follows:-
[expected output][5]
How do I get the last 3 rows where the revenue is 0

Expected output:-

Dominica MOTO400 250000

Dominica YZM10000 140000

Sao Tome and Principe YZM1000 560000

Algeria MOTO400 0

Algeria YZM1000 0

Sao Tome and Principe MOTO400 0

The code to create the tables and enter the values is :-

```
create table motorcycle_model(id int,name varchar(20),price int);
create table country(id int,name varchar(20));
create table sales(model_id int,country_id int,quantity int,sales_date 
date);
insert into motorcycle_model
values(1,'MOTO400',50000);
insert into motorcycle_model
values(2,'YMZ1000',70000);
insert into country
values(1,'Dominica');
insert into country
values(2,'Algeria');
insert into country
values(3,'Sao Tome and Prinipe');
insert into sales
values(2,3,4,'2018-01-29');
insert into sales
values(2,1,2,'2018-01-19');
insert into sales
values(2,1,2,'2017-12-20');
insert into sales
values(1,2,1,'2017-12-18');
insert into sales
values(1,3,5,'2017-12-10');
insert into sales
values(1,2,5,'2017-12-17');
insert into sales
values(1,1,5,'2018-01-10');
insert into sales
values(2,3,4,'2018-01-01');
insert into sales
values(2,2,3,'2017-12-24');
insert into sales
values(2,1,4,'2017-12-14');
```

Comment: Check https://www.db-fiddle.com/ You can use it to prepare question and paste link to working database example

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Fiddle for this question https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CwfZouzE6gMrMuaaZV5Sf/1

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can `cross join` the models and the countries, then bring the table with a `left join`s. Most likely, you also want to `sum()` the revenues (otherwise having a `group by` clause does not make sense):

```
select c.name, m.name, coalesce(sum(s.quantity * m.price), 0) as revenue 
from country c
cross join motorcycle_model m
left join sales s 
    on  s.model_id = m.id 
    and s.country_id = c.id 
    and s.sales_date >= '2018-01-01'
    and s.sales_date <  '2019-01-01'
group by c.name,m.name
order by m.name;
```

Side notes:

- do not use old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause); instead, use standard, explicit joins, as shown above, which are much more readable, and somehow flexible (as the answer demonstrates)
- conditions that do not apply functions to table columns are more efficient (this relates to `year(s.sales_date)='2018'`)